# Table resizes when there is a tree in column

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Below I am posting some code that I am using to try to set a table width to be fixed proportions for each column. 10% for one, 90% for the other.

Presently, I am inserting a dijit.Tree widget via javascript at the "treeOne" div tag. When this tree opens up, my column grows in width to accomodate. I would like for it to always be 10% wide no matter what, and stop resizing the column. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td  style="overflow:hidden;width:10%;"> Tree</td>
              <td style="width:90%;" > Query</td>                       
         </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
        <td style="overflow:hidden;width:10%;">
                    <div id ="treeOne">Insert Tree here</div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;">
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table cells are supposed to work like this, expanding to accommodate whatever's inside of them.

If you want it to be fixed in size (and chop off the contents in the process), try using CSS with divs instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
.col1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:10%;
}
.col2 {
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}
</style>

<div class="col1">
    <div id ="treeOne">Insert Tree here</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">...</div>
```

Comment: Can you show this in context of a table? I tried doing this putting "col1" around my <td> containing the expanding tree, and col2 around the other <td> that had the other 90% and it didnt work as expected. However, if I put col1 div around my tree div directly as you have done, it does in fact chop the display so I can't see everything, however, it still forces the table column to resize (i just end up with a cell with 10% of its width occupied, and 90% blank space where the chop happened

Comment: I repeat: don't use tables. Table cells are supposed to resize as needed. Use floating DIVs instead.

Comment: ah..gotcha, thank you, thought you meant in addition to tables